# Co-NP definition

Tags: complexity-classes

The class Co-NP is defined as all the languages $L$ such that $\overline{L} \in NP$. An example that appears in the book of Arora and Barak is of $\overline{SAT}$, which is defined as $\overline{SAT} = \{\phi : \phi \text{ is not satisfiable} \}$. My question is the following, given that $SAT$ corresponds to boolean functions represented with an alphabet (say $\{0,1\}$), then $\overline{SAT}$ should include bitstrings that correspond to non-satisfiable formulas but also butstrings that dont represent a valid boolean formula. Why is then in the book defiend as $\overline{SAT} = \{\phi : \phi \text{ is not satisfiable} \}$?

Shouldn't the definition be something like $\overline{SAT} = \{\phi : \phi \text{ is not satisfiable} \} \cup \{\phi : \phi \text{ does not encode a boolean formula} \}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically and formally, you are right.
However, it is "nicer" to look at languages with sanitized input.
And since detecting if the input does not describe a valid boolean formula is possible in polynomial time, it is sane.
(Formally, you can polynomially reduce the books definition to yours and vice versa)

Comment: Indeed. Computational problems are almost always "promise problems", but we tend to ignore this in many cases because the promise is easily checkable in polynomial time - see section 1.1. in "On Promise Problems" by Oded Goldreich (http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/PSX/prpr-r.pdf).